# C# How to Reference/Use/Set Values of an Object/Instance in 2 Classes

Tags: c#, class, object, properties, instance

I'm working on a short project where the objective is to create a program that calculates net pay.  The user will enter their name, hours worked, and pay rate.  I must use Properties instead of constructors to receive the data.  There should be two classses; the Main class, and a class I called Pay, which will perform calculations and use override ToString() method to display results (using the string.format command).

I'm having an issue where the program is able to display the persons name, the hours worked, and the rate of pay (all of which were user inputted).  However, a number of the other variables are being displayed as "0".  I also cannot figure out how to set these variables so that they are instances of the object "aPay" I created in the Main class.

Should I set these variables as an instance of the aPay object in the Main class or the Pay class?  And if so, how do I go about doing that? I've been trying a number of things over the last hour or so attempting to figure this out, even referencing a similar program I had as an assignment last week, but I can't seem to wrap my head around this concept and its correct implementation.

I will post my code below, any help and explanations would be sincerely appreciated.

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Header();
        Directions();

        Pay aPay = new Pay();
        Write("**********************************\n");
        Write("Enter name:  ");
        aPay.WorkerName = ReadLine();

        Write("Enter hours: ");
        aPay.HoursWorked = double.Parse(ReadLine());

        Write("Enter rate:  ");
        aPay.RateOfPay = double.Parse(ReadLine());
        Write("**********************************\n");



        WriteLine(aPay.ToString());




    }

    private static void Header()
    {
        WriteLine("*************************************************************");
        WriteLine("\t Pay");
        WriteLine("\t Calculate Net Pay");
        WriteLine("\t Matt Craig");
        WriteLine("\t " + DateTime.Today);
        WriteLine("*************************************************************");
    }

    private static void Directions()
    {
        WriteLine("This program will determine pay.");
        WriteLine(" ");
        WriteLine("You will be asked to enter hours worked" 
                  + "\n and rate of pay");
        WriteLine(" ");
        WriteLine("*************************************************************");
    }
}
```

That was the Main class, I'll post the Pay class below:

```
public class Pay
{
    private string workerName;
    private double hoursWorked;
    private double rateOfPay;
    private double grossPay;
    private double netPay;
    private double FICA_TAX = 0.0765;
    private double FED_TAX = 0.20;
    private double STATE_TAX = 0.10;
    private double HEALTH_INS = 0.07;
    private double ficaTax;
    private double fedTax;
    private double stateTax;
    private double healthIns;

    public Pay()
    {
        /* Pay aPay = new Pay();
        aPay.grossPay = grossPay;
        aPay.netPay = netPay;
        aPay.ficaTax = ficaTax;
        aPay.fedTax = fedTax;
        aPay.stateTax = stateTax;
        aPay.healthIns = healthIns; */
    }

    public string WorkerName
    {
        set
        {
            workerName = value;
        }
    }

    public double HoursWorked
    {
        set
        {
            hoursWorked = value;
        }
    }

    public double RateOfPay
    {
        set
        {
            rateOfPay = value;
        }
    }

    public double GrossPay
    {
        get
        {
            grossPay = (hoursWorked * rateOfPay);
            return grossPay;
        }
    }

    public double NetPay
    {
        get
        {
            netPay = grossPay - FICA_TAX - FED_TAX - STATE_TAX - HEALTH_INS;
            return netPay;
        }
    }

    public double FicaTax
    {
        get
        {
            ficaTax = FICA_TAX * grossPay;
            return ficaTax;
        }
    }

    public double FedTax
    {
        get
        {
            fedTax = FED_TAX * grossPay;
            return fedTax;
        }
    }

    public double StateTax
    {
        get
        {
            stateTax = STATE_TAX * grossPay;
            return stateTax;
        }
    }

    public double HealthIns
    {
        get
        {
            healthIns = HEALTH_INS * grossPay;
            return healthIns;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string stats;
        stats = string.Format("Name\t\t  {0} \n", workerName);
        stats += string.Format("Gross Pay\t  {0} \n", grossPay);
        stats += string.Format("FICA tax\t  {0} \n", ficaTax);
        stats += string.Format("Federal tax\t  {0} \n", fedTax);
        stats += string.Format("State tax\t  {0} \n", stateTax);
        stats += string.Format("Health Insurance  {0} \n", healthIns);
        stats += string.Format("Net pay\t\t  {0} \n", netPay);
        return stats;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are not calling the getters inside `ToString`, you are calling the fields and they don't have a value until you pass by the get methods of your properties.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string stats;
    stats = string.Format("Name\t\t  {0} \n", workerName);
    stats += string.Format("Gross Pay\t  {0} \n", GrossPay);
    stats += string.Format("FICA tax\t  {0} \n", FicaTax);
    stats += string.Format("Federal tax\t  {0} \n", FedTax);
    stats += string.Format("State tax\t  {0} \n", StateTax);
    stats += string.Format("Health Insurance  {0} \n", HealthIns);
    stats += string.Format("Net pay\t\t  {0} \n", NetPay);
    return stats;
}
```

See that I changed the names to start with uppercase so that they refer to the properties.

Comment: Thank you so much for four answer.  I could have sworn I tried that already, but I may not have, or I may tried that at an earlier stage in my writing the program.  You've been very helpful!

Comment: These values aren't instances of the aPay object, correct?  Do I need to assign the user inputted values of WorkerName, HoursWorked, and RateOfPay to aPay? If so, are the other values which are only included in the Pay class also aPay instances? (grossPay, ficaTax, fedTax, stateTax, healthIns, netPay)

Comment: And if so, can I do something similar to this:                                      Write("Enter name:  ");
        aPay.WorkerName = ReadLine();     to the non user-inputted variables that are only included in the Pay class, to make them instances of the aPay object?

Comment: You don't need to make the other values part ot the `aPay` instance, there is no point in saving the information since they can be easily computed when necessary. Save only what is essential (unless calculating it is really expensive), in this case: `workerName`, `hoursWorked` and `rateOfPay`. When you do `aPay.WorkerName = ReadLine()` the value is saved as part of the `aPay` instance. Personally, I would do it like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/nGVnWJ

Comment: is there any way for me to store those other values as part of the aPay instance without printing them to the console like you did with Console.WriteLine(aPay.FedTax);  I want to store them all in the aPay instance so I can complete that instance. However, I dont want any more output to the console than I already have.  I just want a complete aPay instance with values for each of the variables.  The 3 user-inputted variables are already stored in their respective aPay instances, I want to do the same for the other values that are not inputted by the user.

Comment: could I do/change my current code segment to this: Pay aPay = new Pay { variables and values placed here};               or since I already  created the object, could I do something like this : Pay aPay = {variables and values placed here }; or this: Pay aPay {variables and values placed here };  Which would be correct?  Does this work? Or is there a way to add each variable instance to the object seperately without outputting anything?  Thanks for you're help btw, I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: The thing is the aPay instance is already completed, I just added the `WriteLine` as an example, but you could use those properties to perform any operation you want. You can create an instance like this `Pay aPay = new Pay() {WorkerName = "Snags", HoursWorked = 10};` but you can only assign values to the properties with a public setter.